# ant run task : [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Tags: ant, jar, runtime

i try to run my app from ant , the app is using log4j jar 
i have now this ant task:

```
<property name="main-class"  value="com.controller.core.Controller"/>
<target name="dist"  
        description="generate the distribution" >
    <jar jarfile="${dist}/lib/controller.jar" basedir="${build}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
     <path id="class.path">
          <fileset dir="..\lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
          </fileset>      
      </path>
     <target name="run">
            <java jar="${dist}/lib/controller.jar" fork="true" >         
            <classpath refid="class.path" />
            <classpath>
                <path location="../lib/misc"/>
            </classpath>
           </java>      
      </target>
```

or i even gave it full path but still the same error

```
<target name="run">
        <java jar="${dist}/lib/controller.jar" fork="true" >         
            <classpath>
                <path refid="test.classpath"/>
                <path location="d:\dev\svn\trunk\lib\misc\log4j.jar"/>
            </classpath>     
        </java>
</target>
```

where the log4j is in the ../lib/misc path . 
but still im getting this error:

```
run:
     [java] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
     [java]     at com.controller.core.Controller.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
     [java] Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
     [java]     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
     [java]     at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
     [java]     at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
     [java]     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
     [java]     ... 1 more
     [java] Exception in thread "main"
     [java] Java Result: 1
```

now when i run ant with -v flag it gives me this msg :

```
[java] When using 'jar' attribute classpath-settings are ignored. See the manual for more information.
    [java] Executing 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\jre\bin\java.exe' with arguments:
    [java] '-classpath'
    [java] 'd:\dev\svn\trunk\lib\misc\log4j.jar'
    [java] '-jar'
    [java] 'D:\dev\svn\trunk\controller\dist\lib\controller.jar'
```

what do i miss here ?

Comment: Your <classpath> elements aren't nested under the <java> task. It should look like: <java><classpath/></java>

Comment: i fix the question but the same error

Comment: I believe you'll have to use Ant's -lib command line option to specify the log4j library: ant run -lib d:\dev\svn\trunk\lib\misc\log4j.jar . See http://ant.apache.org/faq.html#delegating-classloader.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is just as it says: when using the `jar` attribute the provided classpath is ignored because the jar file overrides it. The ant manual links to the java documentation which says:

> When you use this option [-jar], the JAR file is the source of all user classes, and other user class path settings are ignored.

Instead, include the jar in the classpath and use the classname attribute. For example,

```
<java classname="${main-class}" fork="true" >         
  <classpath>
    <path refid="class.path" />
    <pathelement location="../lib/misc"/>
    <pathelement location="${dist}/lib/controller.jar"/>
  </classpath>
</java>
```